# using jquery dialog multiple times with slightly different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a site in which there are alot of confirm pages and need for a dialog window.  Im am wondering if there is a better way to write my code so that i dont have to spell out all of the dialog parameters every single time.  Each dialog may have 1 thing different. usually the complete button is different function.

for example:

```
  $('#dialogA').dialog(
    {
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: 
    {
            "Complete": function() 
            {
                 //DO SOMETHING FOR A(possible print results of something)
            }
    }
    });
```

and another

```
    $('#dialogB').dialog(
    {
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: 
    {
            "Complete": function() 
            {
                 //DO SOMETHING FOR B (possibly some ajax call)
            }
    }
    });
```

so the only thing that changes is what the Complete button does.  in laymen's terms i guess is I want to set a variable the contains all the dialog parameters....

Comment: Have you tried using the Complete: function(param) with this and storing self? And a parser (i.e., if or switch) inside the Complete function to determine how it should behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
    confirmDialog: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            autoOpen:false,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons:
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        $(this).dialog(options);
        }           
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and call it like this:

```
 $('#dialogB').dialog({Complete: function() { … }; });
```

You can also override the defaults when call the dialog...